# How put a text in a <textarea> using TinyMCE and jQuery

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I have a problem, maybe due to TinyMCE.

I want to put a text in a  markup with jQuery.

This is my code :

```
$(".page").change(function(){
  tinyMCE.triggerSave(true, true);
  $(".description").val("my text");
});
```

Have you an answer to this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('.description').tinymce().execCommand('mceInsertRawHTML', false, "my text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$(".page").change(function(){
  var ed = tinyMCE.get(0);
  var contents = ed.getContent();
  tinyMCE.triggerSave(true, true);
  $('.description').val(contents);
});
```

Comment: The problem is still alive :(